# Is it possible to make a href with bigger bottom padding for an arrow

Tags: html, css, href, css-shapes

I want to make top menu with arrow image on hover, that will display on border line of the next div.

[My fast made fiddle:](https://jsfiddle.net/c69352r3/)

and an image of what I want to do

[image]

**HTML**

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="" alt="" id="logo" />
    <ul id="topmenu">
        <li><a href="" title="">item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="" title="">item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="" title="">item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="full-width-page">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="header-image">
            image with content goes here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.wrapper {
    width: 800px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.full-width-page {
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#logo {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: gray;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

#topmenu {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 20px;
}

#topmenu li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#topmenu li a:hover {
    background-image: url(http://www.ristatebassmasters.com/images/smallDownArrow.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center 8px;
}

#header-image {
    height: 200px;
    line-height: 200px;
}
```

I know that there is a solution to create the menu to be `position: absolute`. And then making `padding-bottom` on href will push the arrow down further, but when the menu will be positioned absolute I will not be able to push it using `float: right`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an **[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c69352r3/4/)** of what you want.

CSS

```
#topmenu {
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
#topmenu li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#topmenu li a{
    padding-bottom: 30px; 
}
#topmenu li a:hover {
    background-image: url(http://www.ristatebassmasters.com/images/smallDownArrow.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center 32px;

}
#header-image {
    height: 200px;
    line-height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Thank You, as I tested all the solutions, Yours seems to be the best one.

Answer (score 0):

I've added `padding-bottom` to you `<a>` elements from menu and it works like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/c69352r3/1/)

Check and write if it's ok for You :)

Comment: Dzięki, to jest to czego szukałem. Kombinowałem z tym, ale nie działało i dalej nie działa. Nie wiem co jest grane, teraz staram się porównać mój oryginalne kod z tym. Musi być jakaś kolizja... Raz jeszcze dzięki.